# Separating front end assets from back end server in spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-2, spring-boot

I'm very new to spring, I created a project and would like to be able to run the project with both node and spring, so i would like to separate the project into a structure like this:

```
myapp
| _____ui 
|      |______ js 
|      |______ css 
|
|______server
|      |____src/main/java etc 
|
```

i have created the following pom files

pom.xml in myapp directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-resource-handling</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Spring Resource Handling</name>

    <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <modules>
            <module>server</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
            <repository>
                    <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                <name>spring-snapshots</name>
                    <snapshots/>
                    <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                    <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                    <name>spring-snapshots</name>
                    <snapshots/>
                    <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

pom file in myapp/server directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
            <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.6</version>
                            <configuration>
                                    <webResources>
                                            <resource>
                                            <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                                            <directory>../ui</directory>
                                            </resource>
                                    </webResources>
                            </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
```

so I'm trying to use the pom file to copy the resources file before the build

```
           <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.6</version>
                            <configuration>
                                    <webResources>
                                            <resource>
                                            <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                                            <directory>../ui</directory>
                                            </resource>
                                    </webResources>
                            </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
```

does this even going to work?? currently I can't find my js files in the target directory when i do mvn package - is there a better way of doing this?